# Cómo importar módulos .py de subcarpetas a carpetas

Tags: python

He estado buscando en la red ¿cuál es la mejor forma de importar módulos en Python? y me he encontrado estas tres:

- Modificando `PYTHONPATH`.
- Agregando el directorio con `sys.append("/ruta_directorio")`.
- Con un archivo `.pth`.

Mi estructura es la siguiente:

```
project
├── carpeta1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── archivo.py
│   ├── archivo2.py
│   └── subcarpeta1
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── archivo3.py
└── main.py
```

La cuestión es que necesito importar algo de `archivo.py` en `archivo3.py`. Tanto `carpeta1` como `carpeta2` tienen el archivo `__init__.py`.

¿Alguien podría indicarme cuál es el procedimiento para ello?.

#### Actualización (detalles)

Tanto carpeta1 como carpeta2 tienen el archivo `init.py`.

Comment: Este es un video de 3hs que explica todo lo que necesitas saber sobre como tratar con paquetes
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0

Answer (score 13):

Si estás en `archivo3.py` y quieres importar algo de `archivo.py` solo necesitas:

```
from carpeta1.archivo import foo
```

Ya que el directorio del script principal (`main.py`) esta en el `PYTHONPATH` por omisión no es necesario modificarlo. Solo importar tal y como lo harías desde `main.py`.

Answer (score 5):

Suponiendo que estás ejecutando `main.py`, no necesitas modificar nada. Tienes dos posibilidades: usando imports absolutos o imports relativos.

```
from carpeta1 import archivo  # absoluto
import ..archivo  # relativo
```

Lo acabo de comprobar:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.5.0 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
$ cat main.py 
from carpeta1.subcarpeta1.archivo3 import VERSION_REL, VERSION_ABS
print(VERSION_REL, VERSION_ABS)
$ cat carpeta1/archivo.py 
VERSION = 2.0
$ cat carpeta1/subcarpeta1/archivo3.py 
from ..archivo import VERSION as VERSION_REL
from carpeta1.archivo import VERSION as VERSION_ABS
$ python main.py 
2.0 2.0
```

Comment: Usando el import absoluto. ¿Es válido usar tal como lo escribes "from carpeta1 import archivo  # absoluto" si importo desde otra subcarpeta de "subcarpeta1"?

Answer (score 2):

Solo debes poner antes la referencia al módulo que vas a usar de la siguientes maneras:

- Todo lo que tiene el Módulo

  `from Modulo import *`

  o

  `import Modulo`
- Si vas a importar solo una función puedes usar

  `from Modulo import function`

Si no están en el mismo paquete debes preceder el nombre del paquete de acuerdo a tu jerarquía.