# Como llamar a una función que está en otra carpeta

Tags: python

Quiero llamar a la función **functions.py** desde **script.py** cómo debo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado **Folder1.functions import *** pero he obtenido este error:

> No module named 'Folder1'

Answer (score 2):

Existen varias maneras de solucionar este problema.

1. Importación absoluta

Si conviertes MainFolder en un módulo, puedes importar Folder1 o Folder2 desde ese módulo. Para hacerlo, sigue estos pasos:

Crea un archivo vacío llamado `MainFolder/__init__.py` para convertir MainFolder en un módulo.

Dentro de MainFolder/Folder2/script.py, escribe `from MainFolder.Folder1 import *`

Para probar el código, ejecuta `python` *en MainFolder* y entra:

```
>>>from Folder2 import script
```

2. Importación relativa

Sigue los pasos de 1, pero en lugar de escribir `from MainFolder.Folder1 import *`, se escribe `from ..Folder1 import *`

3. Modificar sys.path

Para encontrar el código fuente de los librerías, Python recorre los directorios listados en sys.path. Se puede agregar cualquier directorio a esta lista de la manera siguiente:

(Dentro de Folder2/script.py)

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.path[0]),"Folder1")
from functions import *
```

**Explicación**

`sys.path[0]` contiene la ruta del directorio padre del archivo.

`os.path.dirname(ruta)` es más portable que `ruta + "/.."`

`os.path.join(ruta1, ruta2)` es más portable que `ruta1 + ruta2`

Se usa `sys.path.insert` en lugar de `sys.path.append` porque se quiere insertar el directorio al principio de la lista, para que Python lo visite primero. Entonces, si definirías algún módulo cuyo nombre reemplaza un módulo "builtin" de Python, Python importaría tu código en lugar del código builtin.

**Aviso**

Es muy importante que en el caso de 1 y 2, se ejecute `python` *en MainFolder*. En el caso de 3, no importa dónde se ejecuta el código.

**Referencias (en inglés)**

Una explicación muy completo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912

Documentación oficial

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Cómo agregar directorios a sys.path

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath#16114586

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259070/struggling-to-append-a-relative-path-to-my-sys-path

https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath

Importación relativa y absoluta

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python

Por qué se necesita ejecutar python en MainFolder

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166821/valueerror-attempted-relative-import-beyond-top-level-package

Answer (score 0):

La función listdir (list directory) retorna una lista que contiene archivos y carpetas en una determinada ubicación.

```
import os
os.listdir ("C:\\")
```

Te recomiendo visitar esta pregunta: 
[Cómo importar módulos .py de subcarpetas a carpetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087/c%C3%B3mo-importar-m%C3%B3dulos-py-de-subcarpetas-a-carpetas)

Answer (score -1):

En teoría no se puede, porque python solo busca en el directorio de ejecución del script, además de las rutas de entorno de sus propias librerías.
Sin embargo, se puede apuntar a otro directorio desde el cual se puede añadir módulos. En tu caso, sería de la siguiente forma.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../Folder1/')
import functions
```

Referencia: [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)