# Error al importar archivo en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Desde el archivo "gramatica.py" necesito importar una clase que se encuentra en el archivo "aritmeticas.py", este es el esquema de mi proyecto (gramatica.py está afuera de src):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así hago la importación desde el archivo gramatica.py:

```
from src.Expresiones.aritmeticas import Aritmetica
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> File "gramatica.py", line 5, in 
> from src.Expresiones.aritmeticas import Aritmetica
> ImportError: No module named src.Expresiones.aritmeticas

Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: _gramatica.py_ está dentro de _src_. ¿Acaso no debería ser _Expresiones.aritmeticas_ nada más? (Salvo que esté viendo mal el árbol...)

Comment: @padaleiana  sí, gramática está afuera de src

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/408938/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-src)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo llamar a una función que está en otra carpeta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333636)